# How to cache only anonymous(non-login) with ruby grape / garner?

Tags: ruby, caching, devise, ruby-grape

I'm using grape for api, devise for authentication, and thinking garner about caching api response.
I want to cache api response only if user-request hasn't login info.( Non-login status ). Then, how to do it?

1. logined request serves normal response without caching, don't expires cache data(don't affect with caching).
2. non-logined request serves response with caching

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/artsy/garner/issues/87#issuecomment-71453390

`You need to bind with a different key depending on the logged in state. A nice way to accomplish that is to add a different_for_logged_in helper`